# Как на вордпрессе сделать определенный вид всех записей в конкретной рубрике?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте есть рубрика "город доставки", в которой порядка 50 записей. Для всех них нужно расставить одну и ту же обложку. Делать в ручную очевидно геморно, и возникает вопрос, можно ли добавить настройку по умолчанию для определенной рубрики? спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "обложка"? Опиши нормально в вопросе.

Comment: добавил скрины.

Comment: На странице рубрики одна и та же картинка - не айс. Вроде были плагины генерящие изображения, но надо смотреть как они работают - могут создавать нагрузку если не в медиатеку пишут, а на лету это делают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для всех них нужно расставить одну и ту же обложку.

Это называется не "обложка", а изображения записи". Так и написано в интерфейсе.

Чтобы массово установить для записей одинаковое изображение есть готовые плагины. Например https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-plus/

Comment: спасибо большое